# Converting Flv videos to mp4 using Xuggle?

Tags: java, video, mp4, flv, xuggle

How can flv videos be converted to Mp4 format using Xuggle? Which api methods do I need to look into? Any links / pointers would be helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [javadoc](http://www.xuggle.com/public/documentation/java/api/),

> How simple? Here's some code to open a MPEG video file, convert it to an Adobe Flash Video file:

```
IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.newReader("input.mpg");
reader.addListener(ToolFactory.newWriter("output.flv", reader));
while (reader.readPacket() == null)
  ;
```

This method should work for all the formats supported by xuggle.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727590/what-codecs-does-xuggler-support) it looks like this is the list of supported codecs,

```
 Codecs:
 D..... = Decoding supported
 .E.... = Encoding supported
 ..V... = Video codec
 ..A... = Audio codec
 ..S... = Subtitle codec
 ...S.. = Supports draw_horiz_band
 ....D. = Supports direct rendering method 1
 .....T = Supports weird frame truncation
 ------
 D V D  4xm             4X Movie
 D V D  8bps            QuickTime 8BPS video
 D A    8svx_exp        8SVX exponential
 D A    8svx_fib        8SVX fibonacci
 D V D  FRWU            Forward Uncompressed
  EV    a64multi        Multicolor charset for Commodore 64
  EV    a64multi5       Multicolor charset for Commodore 64, extended with 5th color (colram)
 DEA    aac             Advanced Audio Coding
 D A    aac_latm        AAC LATM (Advanced Audio Codec LATM syntax)
 D V D  aasc            Autodesk RLE
 DEA    ac3             ATSC A/52A (AC-3)
  EA    ac3_fixed       ATSC A/52A (AC-3)
 D A    adpcm_4xm       ADPCM 4X Movie
 DEA    adpcm_adx       SEGA CRI ADX ADPCM
 D A    adpcm_ct        ADPCM Creative Technology
 D A    adpcm_ea        ADPCM Electronic Arts
 D A    adpcm_ea_maxis_xa ADPCM Electronic Arts Maxis CDROM XA
 D A    adpcm_ea_r1     ADPCM Electronic Arts R1
 D A    adpcm_ea_r2     ADPCM Electronic Arts R2
 D A    adpcm_ea_r3     ADPCM Electronic Arts R3
 D A    adpcm_ea_xas    ADPCM Electronic Arts XAS
 D A    adpcm_ima_amv   ADPCM IMA AMV
 D A    adpcm_ima_dk3   ADPCM IMA Duck DK3
 D A    adpcm_ima_dk4   ADPCM IMA Duck DK4
 D A    adpcm_ima_ea_eacs ADPCM IMA Electronic Arts EACS
 D A    adpcm_ima_ea_sead ADPCM IMA Electronic Arts SEAD
 D A    adpcm_ima_iss   ADPCM IMA Funcom ISS
 DEA    adpcm_ima_qt    ADPCM IMA QuickTime
 D A    adpcm_ima_smjpeg ADPCM IMA Loki SDL MJPEG
 DEA    adpcm_ima_wav   ADPCM IMA WAV
 D A    adpcm_ima_ws    ADPCM IMA Westwood
 DEA    adpcm_ms        ADPCM Microsoft
 D A    adpcm_sbpro_2   ADPCM Sound Blaster Pro 2-bit
 D A    adpcm_sbpro_3   ADPCM Sound Blaster Pro 2.6-bit
 D A    adpcm_sbpro_4   ADPCM Sound Blaster Pro 4-bit
 DEA    adpcm_swf       ADPCM Shockwave Flash
 D A    adpcm_thp       ADPCM Nintendo Gamecube THP
 D A    adpcm_xa        ADPCM CDROM XA
 DEA    adpcm_yamaha    ADPCM Yamaha
 DEA    alac            ALAC (Apple Lossless Audio Codec)
 D A    als             MPEG-4 Audio Lossless Coding (ALS)
 D A    amrnb           Adaptive Multi-Rate NarrowBand
 D A    amrwb           Adaptive Multi-Rate WideBand
 D V    amv             AMV Video
 D V D  anm             Deluxe Paint Animation
 D V D  ansi            ASCII/ANSI art
 D A    ape             Monkey's Audio
 DES    ass             Advanced SubStation Alpha subtitle
 DEV D  asv1            ASUS V1
 DEV D  asv2            ASUS V2
 D A    atrac1          Atrac 1 (Adaptive TRansform Acoustic Coding)
 D A    atrac3          Atrac 3 (Adaptive TRansform Acoustic Coding 3)
 D V D  aura            Auravision AURA
 D V D  aura2           Auravision Aura 2
 D V D  avs             AVS (Audio Video Standard) video
 D V D  bethsoftvid     Bethesda VID video
 D V D  bfi             Brute Force & Ignorance
 D A    binkaudio_dct   Bink Audio (DCT)
 D A    binkaudio_rdft  Bink Audio (RDFT)
 D V    binkvideo       Bink video
 DEV D  bmp             BMP image
 D V D  c93             Interplay C93
 D V D  camstudio       CamStudio
 D V D  camtasia        TechSmith Screen Capture Codec
 D V D  cavs            Chinese AVS video (AVS1-P2, JiZhun profile)
 D V D  cdgraphics      CD Graphics video
 D V D  cinepak         Cinepak
 D V D  cljr            Cirrus Logic AccuPak
 D A    cook            COOK
 D V D  cyuv            Creative YUV (CYUV)
 D A    dca             DCA (DTS Coherent Acoustics)
 D V D  dfa             Chronomaster DFA
 DEV D  dnxhd           VC3/DNxHD
 DEV    dpx             DPX image
 D A    dsicinaudio     Delphine Software International CIN audio
 D V D  dsicinvideo     Delphine Software International CIN video
 DES    dvbsub          DVB subtitles
 DES    dvdsub          DVD subtitles
 DEV D  dvvideo         DV (Digital Video)
 D V D  dxa             Feeble Files/ScummVM DXA
 DEA    eac3            ATSC A/52 E-AC-3
 D V D  eacmv           Electronic Arts CMV video
 D V D  eamad           Electronic Arts Madcow Video
 D V D  eatgq           Electronic Arts TGQ video
 D V    eatgv           Electronic Arts TGV video
 D V D  eatqi           Electronic Arts TQI Video
 D V D  escape124       Escape 124
 DEV D  ffv1            FFmpeg video codec #1
 DEVSD  ffvhuff         Huffyuv FFmpeg variant
 DEA    flac            FLAC (Free Lossless Audio Codec)
 DEV D  flashsv         Flash Screen Video
 D V D  flic            Autodesk Animator Flic video
 DEVSD  flv             Flash Video (FLV) / Sorenson Spark / Sorenson H.263
 D V D  fraps           Fraps
 DEA    g722            G.722 ADPCM
 DEA    g726            G.726 ADPCM
 DEV D  gif             GIF (Graphics Interchange Format)
 D A    gsm             GSM
 D A    gsm_ms          GSM Microsoft variant
 DEV D  h261            H.261
 DEVSDT h263            H.263 / H.263-1996
 D VSD  h263i           Intel H.263
  EV    h263p           H.263+ / H.263-1998 / H.263 version 2
 D V D  h264            H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
 D V D  h264_vdpau      H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (VDPAU acceleration)
 DEVSD  huffyuv         Huffyuv / HuffYUV
 D V D  idcinvideo      id Quake II CIN video
 D V D  iff_byterun1    IFF ByteRun1
 D V D  iff_ilbm        IFF ILBM
 D A    imc             IMC (Intel Music Coder)
 D V D  indeo2          Intel Indeo 2
 D V D  indeo3          Intel Indeo 3
 D V    indeo5          Intel Indeo Video Interactive 5
 D A    interplay_dpcm  DPCM Interplay
 D V D  interplayvideo  Interplay MVE video
 DEV D  jpegls          JPEG-LS
 D V D  jv              Bitmap Brothers JV video
 D V    kgv1            Kega Game Video
 D V D  kmvc            Karl Morton's video codec
 D V D  lagarith        Lagarith lossless
 DEA    libgsm          libgsm GSM
 DEA    libgsm_ms       libgsm GSM Microsoft variant
 DEV    libschroedinger libschroedinger Dirac 2.2
 D A    libspeex        libspeex Speex
  EV    libtheora       libtheora Theora
  EA    libvorbis       libvorbis Vorbis
 DEV    libvpx          libvpx VP8
  EV    ljpeg           Lossless JPEG
 D V D  loco            LOCO
 D A    mace3           MACE (Macintosh Audio Compression/Expansion) 3:1
 D A    mace6           MACE (Macintosh Audio Compression/Expansion) 6:1
 D V D  mdec            Sony PlayStation MDEC (Motion DECoder)
 D V D  mimic           Mimic
 DEV D  mjpeg           MJPEG (Motion JPEG)
 D V D  mjpegb          Apple MJPEG-B
 D A    mlp             MLP (Meridian Lossless Packing)
 D V D  mmvideo         American Laser Games MM Video
 D V D  motionpixels    Motion Pixels video
 D A    mp1             MP1 (MPEG audio layer 1)
 D A    mp1float        MP1 (MPEG audio layer 1)
 DEA    mp2             MP2 (MPEG audio layer 2)
 D A    mp2float        MP2 (MPEG audio layer 2)
 D A    mp3             MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
 D A    mp3adu          ADU (Application Data Unit) MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
 D A    mp3adufloat     ADU (Application Data Unit) MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
 D A    mp3float        MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
 D A    mp3on4          MP3onMP4
 D A    mp3on4float     MP3onMP4
 D A    mpc7            Musepack SV7
 D A    mpc8            Musepack SV8
 DEVSDT mpeg1video      MPEG-1 video
 D V DT mpeg1video_vdpau MPEG-1 video (VDPAU acceleration)
 DEVSDT mpeg2video      MPEG-2 video
 DEVSDT mpeg4           MPEG-4 part 2
 D V DT mpeg4_vdpau     MPEG-4 part 2 (VDPAU)
 D VSDT mpegvideo       MPEG-1 video
 D V DT mpegvideo_vdpau MPEG-1/2 video (VDPAU acceleration)
 D VSDT mpegvideo_xvmc  MPEG-1/2 video XvMC (X-Video Motion Compensation)
 DEVSD  msmpeg4         MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 3
 D VSD  msmpeg4v1       MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 1
 DEVSD  msmpeg4v2       MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 2
 D V D  msrle           Microsoft RLE
 D V D  msvideo1        Microsoft Video 1
 D V D  mszh            LCL (LossLess Codec Library) MSZH
 D V D  mxpeg           Mobotix MxPEG video
 DEA    nellymoser      Nellymoser Asao
 D V D  nuv             NuppelVideo/RTJPEG
 DEV D  pam             PAM (Portable AnyMap) image
 DEV D  pbm             PBM (Portable BitMap) image
 DEA    pcm_alaw        PCM A-law
 D A    pcm_bluray      PCM signed 16|20|24-bit big-endian for Blu-ray media
 D A    pcm_dvd         PCM signed 20|24-bit big-endian
 DEA    pcm_f32be       PCM 32-bit floating point big-endian
 DEA    pcm_f32le       PCM 32-bit floating point little-endian
 DEA    pcm_f64be       PCM 64-bit floating point big-endian
 DEA    pcm_f64le       PCM 64-bit floating point little-endian
 D A    pcm_lxf         PCM signed 20-bit little-endian planar
 DEA    pcm_mulaw       PCM mu-law
 DEA    pcm_s16be       PCM signed 16-bit big-endian
 DEA    pcm_s16le       PCM signed 16-bit little-endian
 D A    pcm_s16le_planar PCM 16-bit little-endian planar
 DEA    pcm_s24be       PCM signed 24-bit big-endian
 DEA    pcm_s24daud     PCM D-Cinema audio signed 24-bit
 DEA    pcm_s24le       PCM signed 24-bit little-endian
 DEA    pcm_s32be       PCM signed 32-bit big-endian
 DEA    pcm_s32le       PCM signed 32-bit little-endian
 DEA    pcm_s8          PCM signed 8-bit
 DEA    pcm_u16be       PCM unsigned 16-bit big-endian
 DEA    pcm_u16le       PCM unsigned 16-bit little-endian
 DEA    pcm_u24be       PCM unsigned 24-bit big-endian
 DEA    pcm_u24le       PCM unsigned 24-bit little-endian
 DEA    pcm_u32be       PCM unsigned 32-bit big-endian
 DEA    pcm_u32le       PCM unsigned 32-bit little-endian
 DEA    pcm_u8          PCM unsigned 8-bit
 DEA    pcm_zork        PCM Zork
 DEV D  pcx             PC Paintbrush PCX image
 DEV D  pgm             PGM (Portable GrayMap) image
 DEV D  pgmyuv          PGMYUV (Portable GrayMap YUV) image
 D S    pgssub          HDMV Presentation Graphic Stream subtitles
 D V D  pictor          Pictor/PC Paint
 DEV D  png             PNG image
 DEV D  ppm             PPM (Portable PixelMap) image
 D V D  ptx             V.Flash PTX image
 D A    qcelp           QCELP / PureVoice
 D A    qdm2            QDesign Music Codec 2
 D V D  qdraw           Apple QuickDraw
 D V D  qpeg            Q-team QPEG
 DEV D  qtrle           QuickTime Animation (RLE) video
 D V D  r10k            AJA Kona 10-bit RGB Codec
 D V D  r210            Uncompressed RGB 10-bit
 DEV    rawvideo        raw video
 DEA    real_144        RealAudio 1.0 (14.4K) encoder
 D A    real_288        RealAudio 2.0 (28.8K)
 D V D  rl2             RL2 video
 DEA    roq_dpcm        id RoQ DPCM
 DEV D  roqvideo        id RoQ video
 D V D  rpza            QuickTime video (RPZA)
 DEV D  rv10            RealVideo 1.0
 DEV D  rv20            RealVideo 2.0
 D V D  rv30            RealVideo 3.0
 D V D  rv40            RealVideo 4.0
 D A    s302m           SMPTE 302M
 DEV    sgi             SGI image
 D A    shorten         Shorten
 D A    sipr            RealAudio SIPR / ACELP.NET
 D A    smackaud        Smacker audio
 D V D  smackvid        Smacker video
 D V D  smc             QuickTime Graphics (SMC)
 DEV D  snow            Snow
 D A    sol_dpcm        DPCM Sol
 D V D  sp5x            Sunplus JPEG (SP5X)
 D S    srt             SubRip subtitle
 D V D  sunrast         Sun Rasterfile image
 DEV D  svq1            Sorenson Vector Quantizer 1 / Sorenson Video 1 / SVQ1
 D VSD  svq3            Sorenson Vector Quantizer 3 / Sorenson Video 3 / SVQ3
 DEV D  targa           Truevision Targa image
 D VSD  theora          Theora
 D V D  thp             Nintendo Gamecube THP video
 D V D  tiertexseqvideo Tiertex Limited SEQ video
 DEV D  tiff            TIFF image
 D V D  tmv             8088flex TMV
 D A    truehd          TrueHD
 D V D  truemotion1     Duck TrueMotion 1.0
 D V D  truemotion2     Duck TrueMotion 2.0
 D A    truespeech      DSP Group TrueSpeech
 D A    tta             True Audio (TTA)
 D A    twinvq          VQF TwinVQ
 D V D  txd             Renderware TXD (TeXture Dictionary) image
 D V D  ultimotion      IBM UltiMotion
 DEV D  v210            Uncompressed 4:2:2 10-bit
 D V D  v210x           Uncompressed 4:2:2 10-bit
 D V    vb              Beam Software VB
 D V D  vc1             SMPTE VC-1
 D V D  vc1_vdpau       SMPTE VC-1 VDPAU
 D V D  vcr1            ATI VCR1
 D A    vmdaudio        Sierra VMD audio
 D V D  vmdvideo        Sierra VMD video
 D V D  vmnc            VMware Screen Codec / VMware Video
 DEA    vorbis          Vorbis
 D VSD  vp3             On2 VP3
 D V D  vp5             On2 VP5
 D V D  vp6             On2 VP6
 D V D  vp6a            On2 VP6 (Flash version, with alpha channel)
 D V D  vp6f            On2 VP6 (Flash version)
 D V D  vp8             On2 VP8
 D V D  vqavideo        Westwood Studios VQA (Vector Quantized Animation) video
 D A    wavpack         WavPack
 D A    wmapro          Windows Media Audio 9 Professional
 DEA    wmav1           Windows Media Audio 1
 DEA    wmav2           Windows Media Audio 2
 D A    wmavoice        Windows Media Audio Voice
 DEVSD  wmv1            Windows Media Video 7
 DEVSD  wmv2            Windows Media Video 8
 D V D  wmv3            Windows Media Video 9
 D V D  wmv3_vdpau      Windows Media Video 9 VDPAU
 D V D  wnv1            Winnov WNV1
 D A    ws_snd1         Westwood Audio (SND1)
 D A    xan_dpcm        DPCM Xan
 D V D  xan_wc3         Wing Commander III / Xan
 D V D  xan_wc4         Wing Commander IV / Xxan
 D V D  xl              Miro VideoXL
 DES    xsub            DivX subtitles (XSUB)
 D V    yop             Psygnosis YOP Video
 DEV D  zlib            LCL (LossLess Codec Library) ZLIB
 DEV D  zmbv            Zip Motion Blocks Video

Note, the names of encoders and decoders do not always match, so there are
several cases where the above table shows encoder only or decoder only entries
even though both encoding and decoding are supported. For example, the h263
decoder corresponds to the h263 and h263p encoders, for file formats it is even
worse.
```

And here's all the file formats:

```
File formats:
 D. = Demuxing supported
 .E = Muxing supported
 --
  E 3g2             3GP2 format
  E 3gp             3GP format
 D  4xm             4X Technologies format
 D  IFF             IFF format
 D  ISS             Funcom ISS format
 D  MTV             MTV format
 DE RoQ             raw id RoQ format
  E a64             a64 - video for Commodore 64
 D  aac             raw ADTS AAC
 DE ac3             raw AC-3
  E adts            ADTS AAC
 D  aea             MD STUDIO audio
 DE aiff            Audio IFF
 DE alaw            PCM A-law format
 DE alsa            ALSA audio output
 DE amr             3GPP AMR file format
 D  anm             Deluxe Paint Animation
 D  apc             CRYO APC format
 D  ape             Monkey's Audio
 D  applehttp       Apple HTTP Live Streaming format
 DE asf             ASF format
  E asf_stream      ASF format
 DE ass             Advanced SubStation Alpha subtitle format
 DE au              SUN AU format
 DE avi             AVI format
  E avm2            Flash 9 (AVM2) format
 D  avs             AVS format
 D  bethsoftvid     Bethesda Softworks VID format
 D  bfi             Brute Force & Ignorance
 D  bink            Bink
 D  c93             Interplay C93
 D  caf             Apple Core Audio Format
 DE cavsvideo       raw Chinese AVS video
 D  cdg             CD Graphics Format
  E crc             CRC testing format
 DE daud            D-Cinema audio format
 D  dfa             Chronomaster DFA
 DE dirac           raw Dirac
 DE dnxhd           raw DNxHD (SMPTE VC-3)
 D  dsicin          Delphine Software International CIN format
 DE dts             raw DTS
 DE dv              DV video format
 D  dv1394          DV1394 A/V grab
  E dvd             MPEG-2 PS format (DVD VOB)
 D  dxa             DXA
 D  ea              Electronic Arts Multimedia Format
 D  ea_cdata        Electronic Arts cdata
 DE eac3            raw E-AC-3
 DE f32be           PCM 32 bit floating-point big-endian format
 DE f32le           PCM 32 bit floating-point little-endian format
 DE f64be           PCM 64 bit floating-point big-endian format
 DE f64le           PCM 64 bit floating-point little-endian format
 D  fbdev           Linux framebuffer
 DE ffm             FFM (FFserver live feed) format
 DE ffmetadata      FFmpeg metadata in text format
 D  film_cpk        Sega FILM/CPK format
 DE filmstrip       Adobe Filmstrip
 DE flac            raw FLAC
 D  flic            FLI/FLC/FLX animation format
 DE flv             FLV format
  E framecrc        framecrc testing format
  E framemd5        Per-frame MD5 testing format
 DE g722            raw G.722
  E gif             GIF Animation
 D  gsm             raw GSM
 DE gxf             GXF format
 DE h261            raw H.261
 DE h263            raw H.263
 DE h264            raw H.264 video format
 D  idcin           id Cinematic format
 DE image2          image2 sequence
 DE image2pipe      piped image2 sequence
 D  ingenient       raw Ingenient MJPEG
 D  ipmovie         Interplay MVE format
  E ipod            iPod H.264 MP4 format
 D  iv8             A format generated by IndigoVision 8000 video server
 DE ivf             On2 IVF
 D  jack            JACK Audio Connection Kit
 D  jv              Bitmap Brothers JV
 D  libdc1394       dc1394 v.2 A/V grab
 D  lmlm4           lmlm4 raw format
 D  lxf             VR native stream format (LXF)
 DE m4v             raw MPEG-4 video format
  E matroska        Matroska file format
 D  matroska,webm   Matroska/WebM file format
  E md5             MD5 testing format
 DE mjpeg           raw MJPEG video
 DE mlp             raw MLP
 D  mm              American Laser Games MM format
 DE mmf             Yamaha SMAF
  E mov             MOV format
 D  mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 QuickTime/MPEG-4/Motion JPEG 2000 format
  E mp2             MPEG audio layer 2
 DE mp3             MPEG audio layer 3
  E mp4             MP4 format
 D  mpc             Musepack
 D  mpc8            Musepack SV8
 DE mpeg            MPEG-1 System format
  E mpeg1video      raw MPEG-1 video
  E mpeg2video      raw MPEG-2 video
 DE mpegts          MPEG-2 transport stream format
 D  mpegtsraw       MPEG-2 raw transport stream format
 D  mpegvideo       raw MPEG video
  E mpjpeg          MIME multipart JPEG format
 D  msnwctcp        MSN TCP Webcam stream
 DE mulaw           PCM mu-law format
 D  mvi             Motion Pixels MVI format
 DE mxf             Material eXchange Format
  E mxf_d10         Material eXchange Format, D-10 Mapping
 D  mxg             MxPEG clip file format
 D  nc              NC camera feed format
 D  nsv             Nullsoft Streaming Video
  E null            raw null video format
 DE nut             NUT format
 D  nuv             NuppelVideo format
 DE ogg             Ogg
 D  oma             Sony OpenMG audio
 DE oss             Open Sound System playback
  E psp             PSP MP4 format
 D  psxstr          Sony Playstation STR format
 D  pva             TechnoTrend PVA file and stream format
 D  qcp             QCP format
 D  r3d             REDCODE R3D format
 DE rawvideo        raw video format
  E rcv             VC-1 test bitstream
 D  rl2             RL2 format
 DE rm              RealMedia format
 D  rpl             RPL/ARMovie format
 DE rso             Lego Mindstorms RSO format
 DE rtp             RTP output format
 DE rtsp            RTSP output format
 DE s16be           PCM signed 16 bit big-endian format
 DE s16le           PCM signed 16 bit little-endian format
 DE s24be           PCM signed 24 bit big-endian format
 DE s24le           PCM signed 24 bit little-endian format
 DE s32be           PCM signed 32 bit big-endian format
 DE s32le           PCM signed 32 bit little-endian format
 DE s8              PCM signed 8 bit format
 DE sap             SAP output format
 D  sdp             SDP
 D  shn             raw Shorten
 D  siff            Beam Software SIFF
 D  smk             Smacker video
 D  sol             Sierra SOL format
 DE sox             SoX native format
 DE spdif           IEC 61937 (used on S/PDIF - IEC958)
 DE srt             SubRip subtitle format
  E svcd            MPEG-2 PS format (VOB)
 DE swf             Flash format
 D  thp             THP
 D  tiertexseq      Tiertex Limited SEQ format
 D  tmv             8088flex TMV
 DE truehd          raw TrueHD
 D  tta             True Audio
 D  tty             Tele-typewriter
 D  txd             Renderware TeXture Dictionary
 DE u16be           PCM unsigned 16 bit big-endian format
 DE u16le           PCM unsigned 16 bit little-endian format
 DE u24be           PCM unsigned 24 bit big-endian format
 DE u24le           PCM unsigned 24 bit little-endian format
 DE u32be           PCM unsigned 32 bit big-endian format
 DE u32le           PCM unsigned 32 bit little-endian format
 DE u8              PCM unsigned 8 bit format
 D  vc1             raw VC-1
 D  vc1test         VC-1 test bitstream format
  E vcd             MPEG-1 System format (VCD)
 D  video4linux2    Video4Linux2 device grab
 D  vmd             Sierra VMD format
  E vob             MPEG-2 PS format (VOB)
 DE voc             Creative Voice file format
 D  vqf             Nippon Telegraph and Telephone Corporation (NTT) TwinVQ
 D  w64             Sony Wave64 format
 DE wav             WAV format
 D  wc3movie        Wing Commander III movie format
  E webm            WebM file format
 D  wsaud           Westwood Studios audio format
 D  wsvqa           Westwood Studios VQA format
 D  wtv             Windows Television (WTV)
 D  wv              WavPack
 D  x11grab         X11grab
 D  xa              Maxis XA File Format
 D  xwma            Microsoft xWMA
 D  yop             Psygnosis YOP Format
 DE yuv4mpegpipe    YUV4MPEG pipe format
```

Comment: Thanks. A question though, will this same method also work for all other video formats, e.g flvs, .avis, .wmvs? Is there any list of which formats / codecs are supported and which aren't?

Comment: Essentially what I'm looking for is to be able to convert .wmvs, .avis, .mp4s into .flv, .ogg, and .webm formats. will that be possible using this method?

Comment: using your solution, other format to mp4 working perfectly....But when i tried mp4 to other.It throwing "A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:"Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [xuggle4152357224662086902.dll+0x736520]....would you please provide any meaningful solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late but this is because you are running a xuggler library which is compiled for linux and 32 Bit in yout 64 Bit Windows. Try either running your application in Java 32Bit or on a linux os