# I have a code that records video with H.264 (MPEG-4) compression, but I want to use MJPEG

Tags: java, h.264, mjpeg, xuggler

I am developing a program that makes images from a camera, compiles a video and stores it in a specified directory. I will use the [ready-made code](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/blob/master/webcam-capture-examples/webcam-capture-video-recording/src/main/java/com/github/sarxos/webcam/Encoder.java) to implement the function of saving video. In this example, H.264 compression is used. But I want the video **recorded in MJPEG compression**. How can I do it?

I have the following working code:

```
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamResolution;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaWriter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IPixelFormat;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.video.ConverterFactory;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.video.IConverter;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Runner implements Runnable {
private static final String PATH = "C:\\temp\\video";
private static final DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ss");
private static final String videoFormat = "mp4";
private static final int COUNT_FRAME = 100;
private Webcam webcam;

@Override
public void run() {
    webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
    webcam.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize());
    webcam.open();

    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    File saveVideo = new File(PATH, String.format("%s - %s.%s", now.format(format), webcam.getName(), videoFormat));

    IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(saveVideo.getAbsolutePath());
    Dimension size = webcam.getViewSize();
    writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MJPEG, size.width, size.height);
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT_FRAME; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        BufferedImage image = ConverterFactory.convertToType(webcam.getImage(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        IConverter converter = ConverterFactory.createConverter(image, IPixelFormat.Type.YUV420P);

        IVideoPicture frame = converter.toPicture(image, (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) * 1000);
        frame.setKeyFrame(i == 0);
        frame.setQuality(0);

        writer.encodeVideo(0, frame);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    writer.close();
    System.out.println("Video recorded in file: " + saveVideo.getAbsolutePath());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new Runner()).start();
}
}
```

I tried using `ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MJPEG` and `videoFormat = "avi"` instead of `ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_H264` and `videoFormat = "mp4"`, but I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: could not open stream 
 com.xuggle.xuggler.IStream@358368560[index:0;id:0;streamcoder:com.xuggle.xuggler.IStreamCoder@358414416[codec=com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec@358354608[type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO;id=CODEC_ID_MJPEG;name=mjpeg;];time base=1/1000000;frame rate=0/0;pixel type=YUV420P;width=640;height=480;];framerate:0/0;timebase:1/90000;direction:OUTBOUND;]: Operation not permitted
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.openStream(MediaWriter.java:1192)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.getStream(MediaWriter.java:1052)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.encodeVideo(MediaWriter.java:742)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.encodeVideo(MediaWriter.java:783)
    at by.zaharik.Runner.run(Runner.java:48)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have file pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>by.zaharik</groupId>
    <artifactId>UseBarCamera</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.sarxos</groupId>
            <artifactId>webcam-capture</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.sarxos</groupId>
            <artifactId>webcam-capture-driver-ipcam</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
            <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
            <version>5.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Do you mean MJPEG? I don't see  MJPAG in this list of [supported formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727590/what-codecs-does-xuggler-support)

Comment: Already fixed on MJPEG.